# RSA attack excercise

Tags: rsa

I am a beginner in cryptography. I studied the RSA algorithm and now I want to solve an exercise.

```
Cipher Text (HEX): 41A387CABD1C144C99E4B44CE2812A7696CE8A9B5941164741E91B82D89886700DD73A61C580BD75DFC0351D3D6BBF644408A77CB421A115C5
Public Key (e, n): (4049, 16395979)
```

If:

```
n = p*q
z= (p-1)*(q-1)
e*d mod z =1
```

And after trying I found:

```
q = 3659
p = 4481
z = 16387840
d = 10118449
```

Now,
1) Is it correct value for d(secret key)?
2) I know that I should compute $c^d mod n$, But c is very big hex! How can I do it? Should I split it first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hex value of $n$ is `0xfa2ecb`, which is 24 bits long, so it looks like you have to process the input 3 bytes at a time.

This is a simple task in Python:

```
c = '41A387CABD1C144C99E4B44CE2812A7696CE8A9B5941164741E91B82D'\
    '89886700DD73A61C580BD75DFC0351D3D6BBF644408A77CB421A115C5'
n = 16395979
d = 10118449

# n.bit_length() is 24, so let's process c 3 bytes at a time...
plaintext = ''
for i in range(0, len(c), 6):
    # Grab 6 digits from c and convert to an integer:
    x = int(c[i:i+6], 16)
    # Decrypt this chunk:
    y = pow(x, d, n)
    # Convert to ASCII and add to output:
    plaintext += hex(y)[2:].zfill(6).decode('hex')

print plaintext
```

---

I'll just unpack the second from last line in case it looks a bit confusing:

- `hex(y)` converts the integer `y` into a hexedecimal string, e.g., `"0x234567"`
- `hex(y)[2:]` strips off the `"0x"` from the beginning of this string
- `zfill(6)` ensures that the resulting string contains 6 characters by adding "0" to the beginning as many times as necessary
- `decode('hex')` converts every pair of hex digits into a byte with the corresponding value.

Comment: **decode('hex')** should returns three chars?

Comment: @user7747790 Yes. If you give it 6 hex chars as input, you'll get three bytes back.

Comment: I decrypted it. _God does not play dice with the universe. Albert Einstein_

Answer (score 0):

You could check, if $e\cdot d\equiv 1 (\bmod z)$. [1] Since your $z=\phi(n)$ and you want to do something like $(m^e)^d \bmod n= m^{ed} \bmod n \overset{!}{\equiv} m$. Therefore, $ed\equiv 1 (\bmod z)$

For decryption check cryptool. [2]

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Generalizations
[2] https://www.cryptool.org/

Comment: Thanks so much. I check and see **e⋅d≡1(mod z)**. But https://www.cryptool.org/ is server downtime! How can I get the plaintext?